# Using index signatures with methods - Typescript 3.5

Tags: typescript

```
interface Keys {
  [key: string]: any
}

const obj: Keys = {
  trimDescription(text: string, length: number): string {
    return text.length > length ? text.substring(0, length - 3) + '...' : text
  }
}

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  console.log(obj[key])
})
```

I'm using `any` in an interface, but that's not the right way to use TS, how can i describe my methods (i plan to add a few more) in my interface?

Comment: Will those functions have the same signature as `trimDescription`?

Comment: They will be different, like `makeUppercase(description: string)`

Comment: What do you need the index signature? It is expected that you need to iterate over the properties of the object as you shown?

Comment: Yes, `obj[key]` i iterate obj variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all dependes in what you need your interface for. The usual is to represent the shape of your object with an interface and therefore explicitly type all the methods and then let the object "implement" it:

```
interface Keys {
    trimDescription(text: string, length: number): string;
    makeUppercase(description: string, active: boolean): string;
}

const obj: Keys = {
    trimDescription(text, length) {
        return text.length > length ? text.substring(0, length - 3) + '...' : text;
    },

    makeUppercase(description, active) {
        // ...
    },
};

(Object.keys(obj) as (keyof Keys)[]).forEach(key => {
    console.log(obj[key]);
});
```

I guess an index signature is not what you want. There is no need for an index signature unless you need some kind of "bag" of properties of some type, then all your properties must conform to that signature.

Also you can infer the type from the object you create:

```
const obj = {
    trimDescription(text: string, length: number): string {
        return text.length > length ? text.substring(0, length - 3) + '...' : text;
    },

    makeUppercase(description: string, active: boolean): string {
        // ...
    },
};

// Inferred from the implict shape of the object
type Keys = typeof obj;

(Object.keys(obj) as (keyof Keys)[]).forEach(key => {
    console.log(obj[key]);
});
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=1#code/LAKAlgdgLgpgTgMwIYGMYAIDSMCeBndAb1HVPSjjAFsARGPFSgByjAHsIAKWADygC50eCpADmAGnQAbGBFFQAFoIgBXKgCN4ASkHDKcgNwkyVJAGsYAVSZN4KJHhicAJvUZgW7CLpFzJqVgA3GEF1NjYZJAgdIV9RIxAAX1BQFA5hdDZ1ACtBbHx0AF4iY1IRWjdmVg5uGD5JGTlFLRKQMnb0OBgoFTgIcjqoADpG+QV0AD5pWTH0AH4BviG8FXU9MU4ABgaZxXQAWnQAZhaAanQAciHri-RBXigE9sTxFLaTcysbOwcnVwYql5-CggjAWsR3h10AB6aHoa5DUroF6gRIJUCcADyORgIKGFnwnCy2RaDnQnAJbAQWFweC0AG0ALpaIYINhwACiqAUFNwRSmEPaaQgeAiMBGbFERJy9IJzISiS0CSAA)

Maybe you should consider to use a class.

The problem with `Object.keys()` is that it returns the type `Array<string>`, but `string` cannot index an object without an index signature. See [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208) for the rationale. The type of the keys of a given object of type `T` is `keyof T`, so with `(Object.keys(obj) as (keyof Keys)[])` I am telling TypeScript that "interprets" the array of keys as type `Array<keyof Keys>` so it can index the object, like `obj[key]`. The main issue is that, in some cases, an object can have other enumerable properties than those expressed in its type so in practice it could not be true that every key given by `Object.keys()` is of type `keyof T`; however, if you are sure that the object does not have other properties, like in the example where `obj` is created from an object literal, then the assertion is safe, but you need to express that explicitly.

Comment: Could you explain, please, in what cases do i need a "bag" of properties? Also this `(Object.keys(obj) as (keyof Keys)[])` removing errors related to missing index signatures.

Comment: @AlexanderKim I edited the answer. About the "bag" of properties I mean something like a dynamic map or dictionary, like `{ [username: string]: number }` where you can store the age of an user by its username, so every property will conform to that index signature. Those object very often doesn't include any function, just data.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Keys {
    [key: string]: (text: string, length: number) => string;
}

const obj: Keys = {
    trimDescription(text: string, length: number): string {
        return text.length > length ? text.substring(0, length - 3) + '...' : text
    }
}

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    console.log(obj[key])
})
```

Comment: `obj[key]` would return an error, because of missing index signatures.

Comment: Okay, but what if i'll add second method: `makeUppercase(description: string, active: boolean)`? I'll have to explicitly add them in an interface?

Comment: If all share same signature then you can have a single index signature to refer all methods. But at the first place, why do you want to define index signature for a set of functions?
Interface is something, which defines the behavior or structure of the object that is accessible elsewhere so that other piece of code can comply with what this interface has to offer. Ideally you should declare all the methods separately in your interface (even if they share same signature). Use index signatures for a collection (array or key value map).